# jQuery $(this) selector accidentally selects more than 1 element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, this, each

I'm using the `.each()` jQuery function together with the `$(this)` selector to effect a hovered div, but because the given divs are close to one another, the `$(this)` selector selects more than one element if I move the mouse too fast.

Is there any way to make sure to force `$(this)` not to select more than one element?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 donation 180">
      <div class="box">
         <div class="cover">
            <h2>Freedom<br>Package</h2>
         </div>
         <form class="form"></form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 donation 200">
      <div class="box">
         <div class="cover">
            <h2>Sovereignty<br>Package</h2>
         </div>
         <form class="form"></form>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 donation 400">
      <div class="box">
         <div class="cover">
            <h2>Royalty<br>Package</h2>
         </div>
         <form class="form"></form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
if($(window).width() < 800 ) {
    $(".form").show();
    $(".cover").hide();
} else {
    $(".donation").each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).children($(".box")).addClass("animated flipInY");
            $(this).children($(".box")).children($(".cover")).fadeOut("", function() {
                $(this).siblings($(".form")).show();
            });
        }, function() {
            $(this).children($(".box")).removeClass("animated flipInY");
            $(this).children($(".box")).children($(".form")).fadeOut("", function() {
                $(this).siblings($(".cover")).show();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I would appreciate your help, Thank You!

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect.  `this` only ever refers to one thing.  What exactly is the bug here?

Comment: How do you know it's selecting more than one element and not that it happens so fast that you think it selects two?

Comment: It's not possible for `this` to be selecting more than one thing. Can you describe in more detail what behaviour you're seeing and what behaviour you expect?

Comment: i mean... it is possible for `$(this)` to select more than one thing, if `this` is a node collection or an array of nodes. but in your case it is not.

Comment: Why are you using `.each()` in the first place?  If all you're doing is setting a `hover` handler, you can just call `.hover()` directly on the matched elements.

Comment: This is when caching your elements come in handy.

Comment: You can view the code n action here: http://keverrachel.iconstudiosny.com/pesach to better understand the issue

Comment: `.children($(".box"))` is incorrect. [please read documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/children) `.siblings($(".form"))` is also wrong for the same reason.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir as you will see [here](http://keverrachel.iconstudiosny.com/pesach/) things get messed up if you move the mouse too fast

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `$(this)`. You can use the value from each.

```
$(".donation").each(function(i, val) {
  alert($(val).attr('class'));
});
```

Comment: i mean, sure, if you want to select all other elements that have said class. that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: The `$(val)` will be each element that has the `donation` class. He's iterating through them. Each val will be the individual object.

Comment: hmm... yeah, i was under the impression you meant use the class after you get it, sorry. still... this wouldn't solve the non-existent problem. :) it's no different than using `this`.